# Git doesn't detect conflict in file when there is a change

Tags: git

I pulled from the remote branch and there was a file with this line of code in it:

```
$productAttributes = $product->ctAttributes;
```

In my local file the same line of code looks like this:

```
$productAttributes = $product->getAttributesAsString();
```

What I did was simply `pull --rebase origin dev`. The `pull` merged this changes without detecting a conficlt between my local and the remote file. It just choosed the remote one. Why is this happening ? This way 
( not showing conflicts ) we are loosing a lot of code sometimes. Where is my bad ?

Comment: Not enough information. Please show the trees of commits involved before and after the rebase.

Comment: If you did not touch the line and the line in your file is how it looked a few commits ago, then this is exactly how git should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conflict does not mean that two lines of code do not match. A conflict means two changes are not compatible.

---

Suppose there is the following code in `origin/master`:

```
var testValue = "A";
```

I `pull` down the latest copy to my local `master`, and both show this line.

If a coworker makes the following change and `push`es it to `origin/master`:

```
var testValue = "B";
```

Now my local copy is different, and we're in the same situation you describe.

---

If I `pull` the latest code, it will just update automatically without any conflict. Why?

Git is attempting to apply the change `var testValue = "A";` -> `var testValue = "B";`. With the current state of my local branch, this change still makes sense, so it is applied.

---

Suppose I make this change before `pull`ing the latest code:

```
var testValue = "C";
```

Now when I `pull` the latest code, Git attempts to apply the change `var testValue = "A";` -> `var testValue = "B";` - but this no longer makes sense since my local code is not `var testValue = "A";` = CONFLICT

---

There's a lot more to it, but I think it can be fairly summed up as:

> Git attempts to apply a change from a specific starting state to a
>   specific ending state - there will be a conflict if the current state
>   does not match the specified starting state, otherwise the change will
>   be applied

Comment: Thank you! Simple and easy understandable! Now the use of fetch and mege separately seems pretty useful I guess.